# Combobox and button in ExtJS Composite field

Tags: extjs

Iam Using compositfield for Combobox and edit button as side by side
for this my code is

```
{
    xtype: 'fieldset',
    title: 'Covered under warranty',
    checkboxToggle: true,
    labelAlign: 'right',
    autoHeight: true,
    width: 730,
    items: [{
        bodyStyle: 'padding-left:5px;',
        layout: 'table',
        autoHeight: true,
        autoWidth: true,
        layoutConfig: {
            columns: 2
        },
        defaults: {
            frame: true,
            style: 'margin: 0 0 1px 3px'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Warranty Manufacturer',
            autoHeight: true,
            width: 360,
            labelWidth: 110,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'compositefield',
                defaults: {
                    height: 20
                },
                fieldLabel: 'Company',
                items: [ComboComanyinWarranty, btnEdit]
            }, {
                xtype: 'compositefield',
                defaults: {
                    height: 20
                },
                fieldLabel: 'Company Location',
                width: 220,
                items: [ComboCompanyLocationInWarranty]
            }, {
                xtype: 'compositefield',
                defaults: {
                    height: 20
                },
                fieldLabel: 'Contact Person',
                width: 220,
                items: [ComboContactPersonInWarranty, {
                    xtype: 'button',
                    text: '...'
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'compositefield',
                defaults: {
                    height: 20
                },
                fieldLabel: 'Contact Phone',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                    value: ''
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'compositefield',
                defaults: {
                    height: 20
                },
                fieldLabel: 'Contact Mobile',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                    value: ''
                }]
            }, {
                xtype: 'compositefield',
                defaults: {
                    height: 20
                },
                fieldLabel: 'Contact Email',
                items: [{
                    xtype: 'displayfield',
                    value: ''
                }]
            }]

        }
   }
```

but buttons are not displaying properly bottom part of the button cut.
so please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ohh it would be nice with an image so we can see what you mean :)

Comment: is this in a specific browser? can you post a working example of your code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `autoheight` isn't working? Try setting it to a fixed height...